# How to use Retrofit to parse JSON object with different sized objects and arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, retrofit

First off, I want to say that I extensively searched how to do this, using the advice from (at the very least) the following links:

[Parsing JSON array that contain objects with different attributes with Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075862/parsing-json-array-that-contain-objects-with-different-attributes-with-retrofit?rq=1)
https://medium.com/@dds861/json-parsing-using-retrofit-and-recycleview-2300d9fdcf15
http://instinctcoder.com/android-studio-parsing-json-using-retrofit/

[How to parse multiple JSON arrays inside a JSON object using Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274551/how-to-parse-multiple-json-arrays-inside-a-json-object-using-gson)

[Using Retrofit to access JSON arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815008/using-retrofit-to-access-json-arrays)

[How to parse list of JSON objects surrounded by [] using Retrofit and GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656827/how-to-parse-list-of-json-objects-surrounded-by-using-retrofit-and-gson)

However, all of the above links show how to parse JSON objects/arrays with the same type of objects, or objects within just one array.

Here is the specific JSON data I'm working with:

```
{  
  "coord":{  
  "lon":-83.92,
  "lat":34.08
},
"weather":[  
  {  
     "id":500,
     "main":"Rain",
     "description":"light rain",
     "icon":"10d"
  }
],
"base":"stations",
"main":{  
  "temp":292.16,
  "pressure":1011,
  "humidity":64,
  "temp_min":290.15,
  "temp_max":294.15
 },
"visibility":16093,
"wind":{  
  "speed":3.6,
  "deg":290,
  "gust":7.7
 },
"clouds":{  
  "all":90
 },
"dt":1524609300,
"sys":{  
  "type":1,
  "id":809,
  "message":0.0057,
  "country":"US",
  "sunrise":1524567171,
  "sunset":1524615295
 },
"id":420007383,
"name":"Athens",
"cod":200
  }
```

I converted it all to pojo using jsonschema2pojo.org. My question is, how can I use retrofit to access a variable like "main" inside the Weather object, when I already have a "main" object in the JSON array? 
For that matter, how can I access any of the inner objects using Retrofit?

I have made the variables all serializable, and experimented using static classes for the objects within the array.

As an example, say I want to retrieve "id" within the "weather" object. My JSONResponse class looks like this:

```
public class JSONResponse {
@SerializedName("weather")
@Expose
private List<Weather> weather = null;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private Main main;
@SerializedName("wind")
@Expose
private Wind wind;
@SerializedName("clouds")
@Expose
private Clouds clouds;
@SerializedName("sys")
@Expose
private Sys sys;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

//getter and setter methods
}
```

And my Weather class looks like this:
    public class Weather {

```
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("main")
    @Expose
    //This describes what the weather is like, e.g. clear or cloudy
    private String main;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    @Expose
    private String icon;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(String main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

}
```

How would I retrieve that data using Retrofit in my main activity?
Would I be better off just using RXJava without Retrofit? If so, how can I go about doing that?
Thanks in advance to anyone who has the patience to answer this question.